# Seaborn histplot alters counts with hue enabled

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am creating a histplot in seaborn.

My dataframe has 12 rows with both `col1` and `col2` set to non-nan values. Both columns are pandas.Categorical type.

If I create a histplot without `hue` set like so:

```
ax = sns.histplot(df, x='col1', palette='coolwarm', alpha=1.0)
```

I get this plot:

[image: hist without hue]

If I add `hue` parameter on col2 like so:

```
ax = sns.histplot(df, x='col1', hue='col2', palette='coolwarm', alpha=1.0)
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title_fontsize=12)
```

The counts change on the first two bars:

[image: hist with hue]

I can't think of any good reason why this should happen, anyone have any suggestions?

edit:

The answer is to set `multiple='stack'` - was confused as this was already occurring on the first column.

Comment: There's two overlapping bars?

Comment: `sns.histplot(..., multiple='stack')` should give the same height as the original

Comment: Ahhh, `multiple='stack'` worked. It's already stacking on  the first column, I assumed that was the default!

Comment: The first column wasn't stacked, it were just two overlapping bars with different heights.